# PHP - how to match streams from two m3u8 playlists through a common part of the stream url?

Tags: php, regex, match

I have two m3u8 playlists containing dozens of streams I tried to match together. Every link from the Playlist01 have its pair in the second one – Playlist02 and each pair have a common channel ID through which I would like to do this match. Playlist01 contains links as:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="Name01" tvg-logo="http://link.png" tvg-chno="100" group-titles="groupone", Name01
path/playlist.php?ch=5101-ab
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="Name02" tvg-logo="http://link.png" tvg-chno="160" group-titles="groupone", Name02
path/playlist.php?ch=5102-ab
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="Name03" tvg-logo="http://link.png" tvg-chno="650" group-titles="groupone", Name03
path/playlist.php?ch=6234-ab
```

Then there is Playlist02 with links such as:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="Name01" tvg-logo="http://link.png" tvg-chno="100" group-titles="groupone", Name01
http://link345/at/a31350ff5/857183/5101-ab.m3u8
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="Name02" tvg-logo="http://link.png" tvg-chno="160" group-titles="groupone", Name02
http://link574/at/bn350frf5/675494/5102-ab.m3u8
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="Name03" tvg-logo="http://link.png" tvg-chno="650" group-titles="groupone", Name03
http://link674/at/g4K7J7h0r/845987/6234-ab.m3u8
```

And of course there is some Playlist.php, which should help me pair links from both playlists together.
In Playlist.php I read data from Playlist02

```
<?php
$string = file_get_contents('playlist02.m3u8'); // reading data from playlist02
preg_match_all('/(?P<tag>#EXTINF:-1)|(?<link>http[^\s]+)/', $string, $match ); // parsing data – I want to get just the url links

$count = count( $match[0] );

$result = [];
$index = -1;

for( $i =0; $i < $count; $i++ ){
    $item = $match[0][$i];

    if( !empty($match['tag'][$i])){
        //is a tag increment the result index
        ++$index;
    }elseif( !empty($match['link'][$i])){
        $result[$index]['link'] = $item ;
    }
}


print_r( $result );
```

Output is:

```
Array 
( 
[0] => Array ( [link] => http://link345/at/a31350ff5/857183/5101-ab.m3u8 ) 
[1] => Array ( [link] => http://link574/at/bn350frf5/675494/5102-ab.m3u8 ) 
[2] => Array ( [link] => http://link674/at/g4K7J7h0r/845987/6234-ab.m3u8) 
)
```

From Playlist01 I get channel ID with method:

```
$channel = $_GET["ch"]; // in "ch" I have channel ID e.g. 5101-ab
$link = $result[$index]['link'] = $item ; // this is full link from playlist02 e.g. http://link345/at/a31350ff5/857183/5101-ab.m3u8
$prefix = substr($link,0,88); // this slice the first part of the link http://link345/at/a31350ff5/857183/ (links are originally much longer, so the numbers (0,88) don’t match this example, I just wanted to shorten them for an illustration..)
$chid = substr($link,88,10); // this slice the channel ID from the link „5101-ab“
```

Could you please help me, what commands should I use to match correct **$prefix** from the Playlist02 to **["ch"]** from Playlist01 according to the **$chid**, as these parameters are common for both playlists?
Maybe my logic of this pairing is not correct and I should choose another approach, but I am PHP beginner and I tried to collect info from this forum, PHP manuals, blend them and build a new working script. This pairing is just the last piece I am missing and can’t do by myself.
In the end I would like to build and url that will be sent to Playlist01, such as:

```
$url = ($prefix.$channel.".m3u8"); // where $channel from playlist01 should belong to correct $prefix from playlist02 - in this case ch=5101-ab, so ith should have had a prefix which stand in [0] => Array
header('Location: '.$url.'');
exit;
?>
```

I would be really gratefull for your help with correct definition of a control structure (for, foreach) that will help me to finish this script. Many thanks for your advice!

Comment: You want to get the url from `$result = [];` matching the `$prefix` ? So if you have `5101-ab` you want to get `http://link345/at/a31350ff5/857183/5101-ab.m3u8`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the channel from a GET parameter, and you want to link it to one of the urls from the array, you might use [preg_grep](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php).

You could shorten the regex to get the links from playlist02 matching urls the end on .m3u8

```
(?<link>http\S+\.m3u8)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wauEvq/1)

Then search in the list of urls from playlist01 using the $channel in a pattern that ends on *.m3u8* like `$channel\.m3u8$` where `$` asserts the end of the string.

Example code

```
$playlist02 = file_get_contents('playlist02.m3u8');
preg_match_all('/(?<link>http\S+\.m3u8)/', $playlist02, $matches);
$channel = preg_quote("5101-ab");
$pattern = "/$channel\.m3u8$/";
$result = preg_grep($pattern, $matches["link"]);
var_export($result);
```

Output

```
array (
  0 => 'http://link345/at/a31350ff5/857183/5101-ab.m3u8',
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped a lot. If I write e.g.` $channel = preg_quote("5101-ab");`  I get its url from playlist02. But if I would like to link each channel from playlist01 to this script thrugh $_GET, can I use it as `$channel = preg_quote($_GET["ch"]);` ?And also I would need to get pure url from the $result, because I will use it for  `#header('Location: '.$result.'');`, where must be the exact URLs. When I `echo`, or `print` the $result it is with `array ( 20 => 'http` Is there an option how to read it just from the "http" to ".m3u"? Thank you again for your help!

Comment: UPDATE: I did it! I used:

`foreach ($result as $url) {
}

header('Location: '.$url.'');
exit;    `

and tried this `$channel = preg_quote($_GET["ch"]);` and everything works perfektly. Thank you very much for your time and patience!